# Different SELECT statement from what I was familiar with

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Why are these statements valid [am Using SQL2008 R2]

```
Select* FROM TableName   --UPDATE: this is not allowed in Oracle (10g)
```

and

```
Select *From TableName  --UPDATE: this is allowed in Oracle (10g)
```

Now this

```
Select*From TableName   --UPDATE: this is not allowed in Oracle (10g)
```

**UPDATE:** All three are allowed in SQL Server

I have known it this way `Select * From TableName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces are not required in these instances to recognize the distinct tokens of the statement.

In general, programming language parsers work by breaking text into distinct tokens. In SQL Server in this instance, the keyword search completes at "select" since you cannot have keywords with a `*`.  The `*` gets put into the next token.

You can even do this (look no space). Ugly as it may be

```
select*from[master]..[spt_values]where[type]='p'
```

Comment: The new syntax you added is funny. Was thinking tokens were generated by splitting on space.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking the reason they are valid or why they are able to perform the operations that you needed i.e. listing all contents- both field, records, and data of a named database- entire named database structure? The reason is that SQL understands, and takes note of its keywords or its inbuilt commands, in as much as you spelt the command words right, it doesnt matter where you place character such as *, it will always work, and the commands will be executed. In as much as the syntax and the structure of the command is complete e.g. SELECT command is complete when you have- SELECT (what(*)) FROM (where(tablename));

If ou want you may add the WHERE command too like: SELECT (what(*)) FROM (where(tablename)) WHERE (condition); it doesnt matter the space inbetween each inbuilt commands or keywords related to SQL.